# Setup completed with warnings

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Not fully installed. After installing 50% show the massage 'Setup completed with warnings' and show the details in view log option.

Something went wrong with the install.

You can troubleshoot the package failures by:

1. Search for solutions using the search URL below for each package failure
2. Modify your selections for the affected workloads or components and then retry the installation
3. Remove the product from your machine and then install again

If the issue has already been reported on the Developer Community, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, we encourage you to create a new issue so that other developers will be able to find solutions or workarounds. You can create a new issue from within the Visual Studio Installer in the upper-right hand corner using the "Provide feedback" button.

```
================================================================================

Package 'Microsoft.Net.4.6.1.FullRedist.Threshold,version=4.6.1055.18' failed to install.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.Net.4.6.1.FullRedist.Threshold;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=2
    Details
        Command executed: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.4.6.1.FullRedist.Threshold,version=4.6.1055.18\dotNetFx-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" /q /norestart /KeepAUPaused /ChainingPackage Visual_Studio_15_Setup /CEIPconsent /log "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20190214111828_045_Microsoft.Net.4.6.1.FullRedist.Threshold.log"
        Return code: 2
        Return code details: The system cannot find the file specified.
    Log
        C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20190214111828_045_Microsoft.Net.4.6.1.FullRedist.Threshold.log
    Impacted workloads
        .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.8.27906.1)
        Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.9.28307.102)
    Impacted components
        .NET desktop development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites,version=15.7.27625.0)
        .NET Framework 4.6.1 development tools (Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentPrerequisites,version=15.8.27825.0)
        .NET Framework 4.6.1 targeting pack (Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.1.TargetingPack,version=15.6.27406.0)
        C# and Visual Basic (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices,version=15.8.27729.1)
        C# and Visual Basic Roslyn compilers (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler,version=15.6.27309.0)
        Entity Framework 6 tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.EntityFramework,version=15.6.27406.0)
        Managed Desktop Workload Core (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,version=15.8.27729.1)
        MSBuild (Microsoft.Component.MSBuild,version=15.7.27520.0)
        Text Template Transformation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Universal Windows Platform tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.9.28119.51)
```

Comment: How many workloads did you choose for installation?

Comment: only .NET desktop development.